# Psql server not starting due to locale error

Tags: linux, postgresql

I'm on Arch Linux. I cannot seem to understand the error log provided below. How can I successfully start the psql server? My psql version is 13.1

```
● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL database server
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2020-12-13 14:14:50 +06; 3min 56s ago
    Process: 19091 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/postgresql-check-db-dir ${PGROOT}/data (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 19093 ExecStart=/usr/bin/postgres -D ${PGROOT}/data (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 19093 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 0

Dec 13 14:14:50 kma-80tj systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL database server...
Dec 13 14:14:50 kma-80tj postgres[19093]: 2020-12-13 14:14:50.660 +06 [19093] LOG:  invalid value for parameter "lc_monetary": "bn_BD"
Dec 13 14:14:50 kma-80tj postgres[19093]: 2020-12-13 14:14:50.660 +06 [19093] LOG:  invalid value for parameter "lc_numeric": "bn_BD"
Dec 13 14:14:50 kma-80tj postgres[19093]: 2020-12-13 14:14:50.660 +06 [19093] LOG:  invalid value for parameter "lc_time": "bn_BD"
Dec 13 14:14:50 kma-80tj postgres[19093]: 2020-12-13 14:14:50.660 +06 [19093] FATAL:  configuration file "/var/lib/postgres/data/postgresql.conf" contains errors
Dec 13 14:14:50 kma-80tj systemd[1]: postgresql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec 13 14:14:50 kma-80tj systemd[1]: postgresql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 13 14:14:50 kma-80tj systemd[1]: Failed to start PostgreSQL database server.
```

Comment: your error message references your configuration file being invalid - post it here with your question.  also this is the wrong place for this question - Server Fault or Super User are better forums

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with my locale settings inside the psql config file as mentioned in the log above. All I had to do was fix those variables inside that files to UTF-8 english.